# How to Cluster two markers on a particular distance in HERE SDK maps with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

When we tried to show the cluster from array of markers, it works but when we zoomed out a lot but want to show it on a particular distance. We mean, if we zoom out then instead of showing the whole earth then cluster, we want to show it as we zoom out a little.

[image: This is the image of markers, you can see, we are far zoomed out but still not showing the cluster]

[image: After a lot of zoomed out, its showing it, but we want it on some distance not that much far.]

Answer (score 0):

Take the [basic example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/4ad3c5f37433cf4fdce6aacae0357799aa984ecc/examples/latest/navigate/android/MapItems/app/src/main/java/com/here/mapitems/MapItemsExample.java#L108) from the *HERE SDK for Android* as a starting point.

Clustering of marker images works by distance. From the API Reference:

> The markers that
> are close to each other are replaced by a single cluster marker.
> Cluster groupings are generated based on geographical distance between
> objects, not based on screen space collision. Hence it is possible,
> that cluster markers can overlap.

What you want to achieve may be possible if you group the markers to a different cluster. You can have multiple cluster groups, but they can overlap.

If you zoom out, marker images that are close enough and belong to the same cluster will become clustered.